# Telerik Rad Customized Theme using RadSkinManager

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-interface, telerik, themes

I need to create a Theme using Telerik Rad Controls for New Client. There are two ways we can do it.

1. [Create and Register Telerik Rad Control Custom skin manually](http://www.telerik.com/blogs/how-to-create-a-custom-skin-with-our-improved-styling-tool-for-asp.net-ajax)
2. [Create and Embed Telerik Rad Control Custom Skin into an Assembly](http://www.telerik.com/forums/tool-for-embedding-custom-skins-into-an-assembly)

In my existing application we have few in-build Telerik themes and they are populated using RadSkinManager as shown below. How can I keep all the themes in RadSkinManager Drop down and add a new customized theme that client is looking for?

```
<telerik:RadSkinManager ID="RadSkinManager" runat="server" ShowChooser="True" Visible="false" PersistenceMode="Session">
</telerik:RadSkinManager>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for you to be able to list a custom theme along side Telerik themes you would be required to follow the below steps.

1. Build your custom theme using one of the options listed under [Creating a Custom Skin](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/general-information/controlling-visual-appearance/creating-a-custom-skin#creating-a-custom-skin). I made use of [Visual Style Builder](http://stylebuilder.telerik.com/) tool to create a theme named `MetroRed` based on an existing Telerik theme and downloaded the theme files.
2. Build a Custom Skin `dll` with [Skin Assembly Builder](http://skinsassemblybuilder.telerik.com/) using your custom theme files as per the steps outlined in [Create a Custom Skin dll from an Existing Custom Skin with Skin's Assembly Builder](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/general-information/controlling-visual-appearance/creating-a-custom-skin#create-a-custom-skin-dll-from-an-existing-custom-skin-with-skins-assembly-builder)
3. In your ASP.NET project add a reference to the custom skin dll created in Step 2 above
4. Modify the `RadSkinManager` declaration as below

E.g. `Default.aspx` where the `SkinChooser` drop down is displayed.

```
<telerik:RadSkinManager ID="RadSkinManager" runat="server" ShowChooser="True">
    <Skins>
        <telerik:SkinReference Assembly="MetroRed" />
    </Skins>
</telerik:RadSkinManager>
```

5. Displaying the custom skin in `SkinChooser` - Add the new skin explicitly in `Default.aspx` page's `Init` (code behind) as below:

E.g. `Default.aspx.cs`

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var skinCombo = RadSkinManager.GetSkinChooser();
    skinCombo.Items.Add(new RadComboBoxItem("Metro Red", "MetroRed"));
}
```

Now the `SkinChooser` would list the custom skin 'Metro Red' along with the rest of the Telerik default themes and the end user would be able to select the preferred theme from the list.

Reference:
[Creating a Custom Skin](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/general-information/controlling-visual-appearance/creating-a-custom-skin#creating-a-custom-skin), 
[Telerik Forum question on Skin chooser](http://www.telerik.com/forums/skin-chooser),
[How to load skins from external assemblies](http://www.telerik.com/support/code-library/how-to-load-skins-from-external-assemblies) - Check out the sample project `RadCustomSkinSelected` uploaded by Tsvetoslav

Comment: fujiFX  - Thanks. Do you know how did you make images work in Custom Theme ? Custom Theme is working fine but images are not populating. Did you follow any extra step to populate images ?

Comment: @Partha: No, frankly I didn't delve into extensive customizing of Telerik theme. And I was only investigating/ looking up as how to list custom theme (done based on an existing theme/ done using the provided Telerik utils).

Comment: Thanks. That's Okay. I'll check it out with Telerik if they can do something. But your earlier comment is pretty helpful. Thank you.